# CRM 2011 json data.d.results undefined but URL shows data

Tags: ajax, json, crm

I'm trying to do a simple odata query and the call is successful, but the results are always undefined.  I've thrown the URL into the description, copy and pasted it, and it works just fine.  I've tested dozens of different ways to see what the object is, and the results are undefined. What am I missing??

---

**UPDATE:** As mentioned below, part of the problem was referencing data.d.results.  When I referenced data.d.results[0], I actually got the error message "Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference."  I wanted to add that here because I found almost NO help when searching for that error message.

The final answer was a combination of:

- data.d for only one result
- correct casing for system fields; "resProd.Description" as opposed to "resProd.description."

---

Back to orig Question:

Below is the code I'm using:

```
    function setOPDefaults() {
        // Create lookup
        var lookupItem = new Array(); 
        lookupItem = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("productid").getValue();

        if (lookupItem != null) 
        {
            var guid = lookupItem[0].id; 
        }

        var crmOrg = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
        var serverUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + (crmOrg == 'userdefined' ? '' : '/' + crmOrg);
        var ODATA_ENDPOINT = "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc";
        var ODATA_PREP  = serverUrl + ODATA_ENDPOINT;

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "json",
            // Tried both of the following URLS (obviously not at the same time)
            url: ODATA_PREP + "/ProductSet(guid'" + guid + "')",
            url: "http://crm/<<orgname>>/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/ProductSet(guid'67BA90A3-39D8-E211-8D1E-0050569A6113')",
            beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {   
                XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
                var resProd = data.d.results; 

                alert(resProd.length); // This is undefined
                // Below is where I load the URL into description just for testing.  
                // When I copy and paste this URL into the browser, it pulls up results with correct data
                Xrm.Page.getAttribute("description").setValue(ODATA_PREP + "/ProductSet(guid'" + guid + "')");
            },
            error: function (XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Ajax call failed: " + textStatus + " - " + errorThrown + " || " + XmlHttpRequest.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're acessing just one record, so try put something like that:

```
data.d
```

data.d.results is used for multiple results. Another thing you can do to validate the results is put your url directly in browser.

Comment: It was actually a combination of things!  As I mentioned in my original, I HAD pasted it in the URL and it pulled up something valid.  One thing I missed mentioning though (and I'll update the original post), I would get "Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference" when attempting to reference data.d.results[0].  You were right about it being data.d.  The OTHER problem is that I was using the incorrect casing.  Going off an example that used "new_something" as opposed to a system field, so "resProd.Description" instead of "resProd.description." Some time away helped this :).

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, I use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/). You can use it to debug your http/https trafic.

Or. If you have crm 2011 RU 12, you can use built-in Chrome debugger. Press F12. In console tab - right click -> Log XMLHttpRequest